# A holomorphic map into a Hilbert space with prescribed orthogonality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

This is a variation of my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345131/a-map-into-a-hilbert-space-with-prescribed-orthogonality).

Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain, and let $L:X\times X\to \mathbb{C}$ be such that $L(x,x)>0$, $L(y,x)=\overline{L(x,y)}$ and $L(\cdot,y)$ is holomorphic, for every $x,y$.

> Does there always exist a holomorphic map $\lambda:X\to H\backslash\{0\}$, where $H$ is the  Hilbert space, such that $\lambda(x)\bot \lambda(y)$ if and only if $L(x,y)=0$?